# Database of given first names by country frequency and year

Tags: data-request, global, names

I have been able to source datasets of:
(i) given first names and their gender
(ii) given first names by country
e.g. https://github.com/MatthiasWinkelmann/firstname-database

But not given first names by their frequency within a country for a given year.

A great example would be the USA SSA database that Hadley included in the babyname R package - but that only includes USA.

Any ideas of similar data but for other countries?

Answer (score 0):

This site: https://data.world/arunbabu/gender-by-names

provides what you are looking for. It has names with gender for Indians!

Comment: These are indeed UK US Indian names with gender, but there is no prevalence data or indication which country the names came from.

Thanks though.

Comment: as in ? you need an official database?